# How can we convert 2014-06-02 04:23:16 UTC to usual excel date time format?

Tags: excel

I am trying to convert the UTC time stamp format to usual Excel Date time format. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)
```

Then format as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," UTC",""))+TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," UTC",""))
```